# "Definitely require to" vs "Definitely required to"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

If you believe that the world is divided into good guys and bad guys, then

> you are definitely **need** to refine your brain.

OR

> you are definitely **require** to refine your brain.

OR

> you are definitely **required** to refine your brain.

Could someone explain me which sentence is correct?

I think "you are definitely **required(needed)**..." sounds a different meaning because it is likely the second person is **required(needed)** by the speaker to refine the former's own brain, something similar to **"You are hired!"** or **"You are needed!"**.

I have found over a million of usages in google with **"you are definitely need to"** but I am not sure if I can use **"you are definitely require to"** in that case.

Comment: Second one is correct. Before I explain, please share your thoughts about the grammar.

Comment: @vickyace question's been updated.

Comment: I think you must have mistyped when searching for those results or rather, Google auto corrected it. "you are definitely need to" and "you are definitely require to" are grammatically wrong. When using "you are" in such a structure it is usually followed by past tense of the verb. In this case, it should be "needed" or "required."

Comment: @vickyace Or you can rewrite the "need" sentence without "are".

Comment: @Peanut One can rewrite it. But how did op find so many results with that usage format, one might think.

Comment: It says about a million results for "you are definitely need to", but only 4 pages. If not just wrong, I guess it could be a localized usage. Several pages I checked were IT related and ME or South Asia origin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In English Present Tense, the simple verb form is used following 'you'. If the Continuous present is needed then then 'you are' requires (-)ing; but this would be be inappropriate here. So, for .1. the correct form is

> you definitely need to refine your brain.

If it is absolutely necessary to use a more formal style, then the same idea in 'officialese' is:

> you are definitely required to refine your brain.

Answer (score 0):

In my perspective third option is correct. "Required to" has been used here as an affirmative action.

Comment: Hi SKN, and welcome to ELU! Please add more detail to your answer, and a source would be appreciated. Thanks!